# Type inference doesn't work

Tags: c#, type-inference

```
class Sample
{
    public static T M<T, TParam1>(TParam1 param1)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double d = Sample.M((int)121);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile and results in the following error message:

> The type arguments for method
>   'ThreadPoolTest.Sample.M(TParam1)' cannot be inferred from
>   the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly

Why isn't type inference working in this example?

Comment: Did you mean inference ?

Comment: @kbok I think it's interference at this point :D

Comment: Oh, yes I mean 'inference'. Thanks for fix! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type inference can only use the *arguments* to the method call. The fact that you're assigning the result to a `double` is entirely irrelevant as far as type inference is concerned. In other words, as far as the compiler is concerned, it needs to work out what this means:

```
Sample.M((int) 121)
```

without any more information. For example, you could mean `Sample.M<int, int>`, or `Sample.M<double, int>`, or `Sample.M<string, int>` - there's no information so say which of those is a better match.

You don't mention `T` in the parameter list, so type inference can't help.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!
Sad that C# doesn't understand, what I mean exactly the type of variable (double in this case).
I think it's obvious in most cases what is exactly the expected type of expression means.
In case then special type is needed it's very simple to specify explicitly like this:

double d = (string)Sample.M((int)121);

At least partial type assigning will be desirable:

double d = Sample.M<string>((int)121);

Answer (score 7):

Jon's answer is of course correct. It is edifying to consider why it is that C# does not consider the "return type" when making inferences. The basic principle here is that type information flows from *inside* to *outside*, not from *outside* to *inside* when analyzing an expression.

In your particular case it is dead obvious what the intended return type is because you are assigning to something that is unambiguously double. But there are plenty of situations where it is not at all obvious:

```
static R M<A, R>(A a) { return default(R); }
static void N(int x, double y) {}
static void N(double x, int y) {}
...
N(M(123), 456);
```

OK, now what? If type information about "what is being assigned to" must flow *in* to the type inference on M then the type information that has to flow in is "it could be int or double".

But wait, is that correct? We can make more logical inferences here about what the possible return type is intended to be.

If it is int, then we have `N(M<int, int>(123), 456)` and overload resolution *on N* will then fail because that call is ambiguous; it could be either version of N!

Therefore it can't be int, right? It has to be double, because that then means that the call is `N(M<int, double>(123), 456)` which is unambiguously the second overload.

Now imagine doing that for a call of the form Q(R(S(N(M(... with a dozen overloads of each, and maybe with a few lambdas thrown in there as well. The analysis gets insanely complex; it gets hard to implement correctly and hard for users to understand what their program does, why it produces errors, and how to fix them.

It is much easier to simply say that **the type analysis of an expression must be determined from its content, not its context**. So that's what we do. The overload resolution problem you are throwing at the compiler must be solvable without looking at the context of the problem; we look only at the content of the argument list to solve the problem, and there is not enough information in the argument list.

Now, lambdas are the exception here. Lambda parameter types *are* inferred from their context, and as a result, you can easily force the compiler to try trillions of possible type assignments for deeply nested lambdas in order to solve an overload resolution problem. But we don't want to extend the difficulties of analyzing lambdas to the entire language; we want to narrowly confine those difficulties to the specific language features that need them.

Comment: What does visual studio ide do if you where too accidental get into a situation that forced a trillion evaluations? Is there some kind of time-out in place to stop the machine/core from locking up? I don't know how to construct a code sample to demonstrate it or I would just try it myself.

Comment: @asawyer: Try this. Suppose you have types X and Y, methods A(Action<X>), A(Action(Y)), B(Action<X>), B(Action<Y>), C... and so on, n of those, and a method M that takes n arguments. Let's say n is 3 and M is M(X, Y, X). Construct a call A(a=>B(b=>C(c=>M(a, b, c))). How does overload resolution resolve the calls to A, B, C and M? It must test every possible combination of "a is X or Y, b is X or Y, c is X or Y" in order to determine that X, Y, X is the *unique best match*. That 2 to the 3 possible combinations.  But you can make that "3" arbitrarily large by nesting deeper.

Comment: @asawyer: and of course if you have overloads of Action<W>, Action<X>, Action<Y>, Action<Z>, then you get 4 to the n possible combinations. If you have m overloads and n nestings then the compiler must try m to the n possible valuations for the n lambda parameters. If m and n are both ten, that's ten billion combinations right there. This makes Visual Studio *extremely unhappy*.

Comment: @asawyer: Of course, no one writes code like that. But in an early version of LINQ, *a "select many" query did generate nested lambdas exactly like that* and a select many query more than eight levels deep would thoroughly mess up the compiler. This is why we introduced "transparent identifiers" as a mechanism in LINQ queries; it allows us to un-nest all those lambdas so that we do not have this absurd overload resolution problem to solve every time someone does a select many query. (The nesting moves into the type of the transparent identifier.)

Comment: @asawyer: To answer your question about Visual Studio: it can certainly lock up, or fail with an out-of-memory, or an 'expression is too complex to compile' error in such cases. I am hoping we can put heuristics into Roslyn that detect such situations before they blow the stack, the heap or run for centuries.

Comment: As usual your posts are fascinating to read. Thank you so much for your detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specified the return type.

Here's what you want:

```
double d = Sample.M<double, int>((int)121);
```

Comment: Actually the explicit (int) cast is redundant.

Comment: Even if `TParam1` were not specified, the literal `121` is an `int`.